# Scraping a table into a dict and writing each row to CSV

Tags: python, csv, collections, dictionary

I have a project that was using Scraperwiki to write to their sqlite store, but I need to just write a [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). The catch is that all the data is stored in a dict, which works fine for writing to sqlite:

```
scraperwiki.sqlite.save(unique_keys = ['somekey'], data = data, table_name='fancy')
```

I run that after I scrape each row. There's no order to a dict so I can't just write the values to CSV. I've been looking over [csv.DictWriter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects), and I'm still wrapping my head around how I'd refactor my code so that I can write data, which is a dictionary to CSV instead. Here's an example of my code as structured now:

```
def store_exception(exception, line_number, some_string):
    data = {
        'timestamp'  : datetime.now(),
        'line_number': line_number,
        'message'    : exception,
        'string'     : some_string
    }
    scraperwiki.sqlite.save(unique_keys = ['timestamp'], data = data, table_name='error_log')
```

I think I want something like this though:

```
def store_exception(exception, line_number, some_string):
    data = {
        'timestamp'  : datetime.now(),
        'line_number': line_number,
        'message'    : exception,
        'string'     : some_string
    }
    d = defaultdict(lambda: "")
    d_order = d['timestamp'],d['line_number'],d['message'],d['string']

    with open('some/path.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        linewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, d_order, delimiter='|',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        linewriter.writerow(data)
```

That seems inefficient, though. Do I need both collections.defaultdict and csv.DictWriter?

Comment: Your code looks good except this: `d = defaultdict(lambda: "")
    d_order = d['timestamp'],d['line_number'],d['message'],d['string']` Just give the list of column names in DictWriter. Or may be I do not understand something?

Comment: @crow16384 I'm trying to figure out whether I need DefaultDict and DictWriter. It sounds like I don't need both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.  You don't need the default_dict at all, `d_order` just needs to be a list for field names, or in this case dict keys:

```
def store_exception(exception, line_number, some_string):
    data = {
        'timestamp'  : datetime.now(),
        'line_number': line_number,
        'message'    : exception,
        'string'     : some_string
    }

    d_order = ['timestamp', 'line_number', 'message', 'string']

    with open('some/path.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        linewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, d_order, delimiter='|',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        linewriter.writerow(data)
```